# Submit Button Not Working on React Movie App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on this Movie Review Project for some time, I'm having difficulty getting the submit button to work.

The way the program works is I have three sections, one section has the movie information, the next has the reviews, and the third is the form that allows the user to take their own rating and it is added to the list of reviews. The only catch is, even with the code I've used prior the list of reviews doesn't get updated. One thing I do notice is that the useState in the App titled movies, it shows all of the data from the .js file of information. However, it should be seen as an "any" data type.

I do want to add my code here as well!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rwqfjz?file=src%2FApp.jsx

So far I've tried changing the parameters, props but with no results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "I do want to add my code here as well!"—why haven't you? If you don't share it here, we can't help you. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is that the reviews value in undefined if you check the console after clicking submit it syas this error

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reviews')

on app.jsx -> 14:21
on userRating 22.4

solved the issue go to movieInfo.jsx and on line 40 or where you are rendering userRating Components you made the movieId={movies.id} rather than {movieInfo.id}!!!...

Comment: Hi there! Thank you so much for reaching out! So I do have one question, for the error on app.jsx  and userRating is there another parameter I should be using? Also I did change the UserRating Component, here's what I have now! 

  <UserRating movieID={movieInfo.id} onAddReview={onAddReview} />

Comment: what other parameter you are talking about? the parameters you giving to userRating components or onAddReview function parameters? i hope you code works now... and i would recemmend you use typescript rather than javascript as it checks for type errros

Comment: Sorry, I meant  if I needed to change this: on app.jsx -> 14:21 on userRating 22.4

Comment: i don't thinks so... if you need help i am also working on one nextJs 14 app with NextAuth and Shadcn/ui

Comment: Ok, I did try it once more and sadly nothing changed, as for Typescript I've been assigned to work in Javascript. Edit: I just saw the rest of your message, yes I'd be more than happy for more help! Should I send my code over again?

Comment: yep, i would like to see your code to help you out...

Comment: Ok, here is a link to what I have so far! 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rwqfjz?file=src%2FUserRating.jsx

Comment: got it. i will check it out and get back soon...

Comment: i updated your code... here's the link... you can add review now!!!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ylw2bs?file=src%2FApp.jsx,src%2FMovieInfo.jsx,src%2FStarRating.jsx,src%2FReviewInfo.jsx,src%2Findex.css,src%2FUserRating.jsx,src%2FApp.css

Comment: review the updated code and check if you can understand... if can't it's good sign you need work on understanding code skills and problem solving...

Comment: I think I see what you changed! You added a set prop to the StarRating value that allows you to set the use states for UserRating, basically you have a prop for one state (Stars={Stars} and then you have another for setting those values which is set={setStars})  Looks like most if not a good chunk of the code was missing due to that. Thanks so much!

Comment: no problem.... hope the app works like charms now with no errors...